# What is wrong specifically with MY code in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is for some reason not functioning properly. The task I had to code for was:

You have been assigned by the FA to record statistics for the Premiership.  To show that you are capable, you are to record statistics for two clubs – Manchester City and Chelsea football clubs.  You should record the names of the players, the team that they play for and the number of goals they have scored so far this season.  You will need to keep separate files for each team.  To keep the task simple you should only record statistics for 5 player per team, initially. You should be able to search for any player and display their record once the data has been saved.  When searching for a particular player a record is not available then an appropriate message should be displayed.

Now the code for my task that I wrote is:

```
#BPL Stats
UserSearch = input("What player would you like to search for?")


Players = []
Goals = []
counter = 0

def StatProcessing(PlayerFileName,PlayerFileLabel,PlayerTeamAttributeLabel,GoalFileName,GoalFileLabel,GoalTeamAttributeLabel):
    global Players
    global Goals

    with open(PlayerFileName,mode = 'r',encoding = 'utf-8') as PlayerFileLabel:
        PlayerTeamAttributeLabel = PlayerFileLabel.readlines()
    for line in PlayerTeamAttributeLabel:
        Players.append(line)

    with open(GoalFileName,mode = 'r',encoding = 'utf-8') as GoalFileLabel:
        GoalTeamAttributeLabel = GoalFileLabel.readlines()
    for line in GoalTeamAttributeLabel:
        Goals.append(line)       

StatProcessing('ChelseaPlayers.txt','ChelseaNamesFile','ChelseaName','ChelseaGoals.txt','ChelseaGoalsFile','ChelseaGoals')
StatProcessing('ManCityPlayers.txt','ManCityNamesFile','ManCityName','ManCityGoals.txt','ManCityGoalsFile','ManCityGoals')

while (counter != 10) or (UserSearch != Players[counter]):

    if UserSearch == Players[counter]:
        if counter <= 4:
            print (UserSearch,"who plays for Chelsea has scored:", Goals[counter], " goals this season")
        if (counter > 4) and (counter <= 9):
             print (UserSearch,"who plays for Manchester City has scored:", Goals[counter], " goals this season")    
        break
    else:
        counter += 1

        if counter > 9:
            print ('The player you searched for is not in the list. Sorry!')
            break
```

The contents for the files are as follows:

ChelseaPlayers.txt:
Costa
Falcao
Remy
Hazard
Pedro

ChelseaGoals.txt:
1
0
0
0
1

ManCityPlayers:
Aguero
Sterling
De Bruyne
Silva
Kompany

ManCityGoals:
1
1
0
1
2

The problem that I have come up with is that when I search 'Costa' when prompted to do so by the program, whilst he is the first element in the Chelsea players' list, and therefore as per the code, the output should be "Costa has scored 1 goals this season" (or something along that line), the message that does come up is that 'This okayer is not in the lost. Sorry!' which doesn't make any sense!

Note that I have tried entering other players and it is the same outcome and I have tried entering the name with spaces and without spaces, still doesn't work.

Comment: please reduce your code to the *absolute minimum* that still reproduces your error. the way you  asked here people here will only vote to close the question.

Comment: Is the file contents exactly as printed here, e.g. Costa Falcao Remy Hazard Pedro
with no linebreaks between?

Comment: @user3468054 I assume as such. Feel free to check over my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is poor quality code and you made this question really convoluted to answer. As suggested by the other commenter, you should minimise the code to exhibit the problem whilst using less code to make it easier to answer.

The main issue is that your code for adding the file to the list didn't work. You should have printed out the list first to check you were searching against the correct data. I rewrote the file opening logic to add based on delimited spaces rather than new lines. I also got rid of the "with" and "as" you were using and replaced it with a regular variable and open.

Your code now executes and appears to return the correct data.

Here is the code for python 2 (replace "raw_input" with "input") if you're using python 3. This code then prints out the following when you search for "Costa": ('Costa', 'who plays for Chelsea has scored:', '1', ' goals this season')

```
#BPL Stats
UserSearch = raw_input("What player would you like to search for?")


Players = []
Goals = []
counter = 0

def StatProcessing(PlayerFileName,PlayerFileLabel,PlayerTeamAttributeLabel,GoalFileName,GoalFileLabel,GoalTeamAttributeLabel):
    global Players
    global Goals

    PlayerFileLabel = open(PlayerFileName,mode = 'r')
    properListPlayer = PlayerFileLabel.read().split()
    for line in properListPlayer:
        Players.append(line)

    GoalFileLabel = open(GoalFileName,mode = 'r')
    properListGoal = GoalFileLabel.read().split()
    for line in properListGoal:
        Goals.append(line)


StatProcessing('ChelseaPlayers.txt','ChelseaNamesFile','ChelseaName','ChelseaGoals.txt','ChelseaGoalsFile','ChelseaGoals')
StatProcessing('ManCityPlayers.txt','ManCityNamesFile','ManCityName','ManCityGoals.txt','ManCityGoalsFile','ManCityGoals')



while (counter != 10) or (UserSearch != Players[counter]):

    if UserSearch == Players[counter]:
        if counter <= 4:
            print (UserSearch,"who plays for Chelsea has scored:", Goals[counter], " goals this season")
        if (counter > 4) and (counter <= 9):
             print (UserSearch,"who plays for Manchester City has scored:", Goals[counter], " goals this season")
        break
    else:
        counter += 1

        if counter > 9:
            print ('The player you searched for is not in the list. Sorry!')
            break
```

Comment: I do appologise for the convulted code/question. i was simply trying to include enough detail to make it easy for you guys to answer. Now firstly a big thank you! The code works. However only for the majority of the players. When I searched 'De Bruyne' or 'Kompany' then it comes up with the message that they are not in the list, even though they are. Also I was wondering could u explain why my 'file' opening was wrong, when i printed the relevant list it had all the players in them but as ['Costa\n', 'Falcao\n'] etc. Is that where I went wrong?

Comment: Doesn't fully solve my problem and I'm unsure as to why it is such. I have already printed the list out and tried to work it out but...